# Establishing connection between Android app and Oracle DB using JDBC driver

Tags: java, android, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I am having trouble establishing a connection between my app and an Oracle DB using JDBC drivers.

Host Oracle ver.: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

.Jar jdbc drivers I have tried: ojdbc5.jar, ojdbc6.jar, ojdbc14.jar, all from oracle itself.
I have granted the application the permission in the manifest.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I get absolutely no response, nothing in the logcat. The SQL statement has no effect on the remote DB.
I can connect the remote DB with the same login credentials on my machine with SQL Plus and have all the privileges.

Code from MainActivity.java

```
package testapp.myapplication;    
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ConnectOra db = new ConnectOra();
            ResultSet rs = db.getResult();
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(rs.getString(1));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);

        }


    }

    public void btn(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));//Just to refresh the mainact.
    }
}
```

Code from ConnectOra.java:

```
package testapp.myapplication;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import android.util.Log;

public class ConnectOra {
    private Connection conn;
    private Statement stmt;
    public ConnectOra() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            System.out.println("in try");
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@103.A.B.C:15210/mdb";
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"XXX","pw");
            this.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            this.stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            Log.d("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public ResultSet getResult() throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp;");
        System.out.println(rset+"");
        stmt.close();
        return rset;
    }
}
```

---

The selected answer works and my code works too.

Android cant work with `ojdbc5.jar`, `ojdbc6.jar` as they require some Java SE components not available on Android. So, we have to use `ojdbc14.jar` since its older than `ojdbc5.jar` and `ojdbc6.jar` and doesn't require advance Java components, this also means that only the basic functions are there with `ojdbc14.jar`.

With `ojdbc14.jar` you might have to set "`SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8`" in `sqlnet.ora` on the remote host running the DB. This will allow older clients to connect to newer DB otherwise it throws the error `ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol.`

It is also vital to `close` the `Connection` and `Statement` after the SQL statements have been executed, else the changes aren't saved in the actual remote DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try out this code and post the error log. Also a word of caution, you really shouldnt do this, you should have an application sever like [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/database-mobile-server/overview/index.html) to manage connections to Oracle DB. But if you wanna play it unsafe, try out this code :

```
String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; //

  String serverName = "localhost";
  String portNumber = "1521";
  String db = "XE";
  String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":"
    + db; // connectOracle is the data
  // source name
  String user = "system"; // username of oracle database
  String pwd = "root"; // password of oracle database
  Connection con = null;
  ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  Socket socket = null;
  DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

  try {
   Class.forName(driver);// for loading the jdbc driver

   System.out.println("JDBC Driver loaded");

   con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);// for
                // establishing
   // connection
   // with database
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
   System.out.println("Listening :8888");

   while (true) {
    try {

     socket = serverSocket.accept();
     System.out.println("Connection Created");
     dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
       socket.getInputStream());
     dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
       socket.getOutputStream());
     System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
     // System.out.println("message: " +
     // dataInputStream.readUTF());

     ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("select * from person");
     while(res.next()){
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
     }

    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (dataInputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataInputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }

    if (dataOutputStream != null) {
     try {
      dataOutputStream.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

And read again, this is not recommended.

Comment: Ofcourse you have to change the port number details and all.

Comment: Will try right away. I know its not safe but then again I dont have any options and the data in the DB isn't sensitive.

Comment: It is not only about that, ideally you shouldn't do that much processing of data on Client side, it should happen on server, and client should recieve only what is necessary. Plus, data can easily go out of sync. I cannot think of any use-case other then trying out something which works fast and later creates bigger problems...

Comment: The DB I need to provide access to isn't capable of the mobile server.
What other way can I try?

Comment: Then how is it going to cater to clients making multiple connections?? If this is just a test, then you are building infrastructure around something which you will later discard....and dont forget the processing part I said...

Comment: Its just a mini project for my internship.
I already built a client using MDK mobile server, which i had to discard due to unavailability of mobile server on their end.

Comment: Ok...Have fun...If u want to learn something out of it, then you can always create a server on your local laptop, host the DB there, connect the laptop to a router which doesnt need to have access to internet, and connect mobile to router as well, you can give the private IP address and use the services provided by DB from the server, and believe me, this is easy to setup. Enjoy.

Comment: I have a local DB as well running on my other PC. :)
But not having fun, installing oracle 12c on my work laptop was a massive pain with some permissions error on the temp dir, so I installed it on my desktop PC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82321/discussion-between-utkarsh-narain-srivastava-and-we-are-borg).

Comment: And edit your main post to include logs, not my answer.

Comment: Did that, all the code buzzed my mind :)

Thanks for all the help.